# What's wrong with css object-fit property

Tags: html, css, properties

I'm really ashamed for this question but I'm working around css "object-fit" and I know that it's a "partial support" property, but I can't make it function, not even in last firefox / chrome versions. I know maybe I'm doing a dumb mistake but I´m search for one day on Internet trying to find a solution but I can't... I try with all vendors... Reducing the markup to its minimal expression like in this example but nothing happens in any browser .

Anyone have a idea what I'm doing wrong?

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border:  2px solid red;
}
    
div img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c4/Original_Image_before_ASTC_compression.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Add `width: 100%; height: 100%;` to your `img` rule

Comment: It works fine! many thanks LGSon

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to LGSon and Oriol.

Adding width and height 100% to the image make object-fit work correctly for my case.

I suppose object-fit needs a established value on width and height from the image to work fine.

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border:  2px solid red;
}
    
.test img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c4/Original_Image_before_ASTC_compression.jpg">
 </div>
```

Best!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you want to set the sizes to the image itself, not its parent.

```css
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border:  2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c4/Original_Image_before_ASTC_compression.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Orior, but I'm planning to use object-fit because I don't want to determine width and height in the image because I don't know which size would be in the final element